# Create new columns with quantiles from a group in r

Tags: r, group-by, quantile

I want to include new columns with quantile 1 y 3 by group

I have this dataframe:

```
d <- data.frame(date = c("2017-02-23", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-23","2018-02-22", "2018-02-22"), 
var1 = c(1,3,6,7,8,5), 
var2 = c(1,3,18,15,25,5))
```

and I would like to have two new columns `Q1var1`, `Q1var2`, `Q1var1` and `Q1var2` like:

```
d = d %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(Q1var1 = quantile(var1,prob = 0.25,na.rm = TRUE))
d = d %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(Q1var2 = quantile(var1,prob = 0.25,na.rm = TRUE))
d = d %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(Q3var1 = quantile(var1,prob = 0.75,na.rm = TRUE))
d = d %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(Q3var2 = quantile(var1,prob = 0.75,na.rm = TRUE))
```

but in a faster way

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to group by 'date', then use `mutate_at` for applying functions on multiple columns, convert the `quantile` output to a `tibble` wrapped in a `list` and then `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(var1, var2), list(Qs = ~ 
     list(as_tibble(as.list(quantile(., prob = c(0.25, 0.75),
         na.rm = TRUE )))))) %>%
  unnest
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   date [3]
#  date        var1  var2 `25%` `75%` `25%1` `75%1`
#  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 2017-02-23     1     1  3.5   6.5       8   16.5
#2 2017-02-22     3     3  3     3         3    3  
#3 2017-02-23     6    18  3.5   6.5       8   16.5
#4 2017-02-23     7    15  3.5   6.5       8   16.5
#5 2018-02-22     8    25  5.75  7.25     10   20  
#6 2018-02-22     5     5  5.75  7.25     10   20
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <-  paste0("Q_", rep(c("var1", "var2"), each = 2), c(".Q25", ".Q75"))
setDT(d)[, (nm1) := unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) 
   as.list(quantile(x, prob = c(0.25, 0.75)))), recursive = FALSE),
          date, .SDcols = var1:var2]
d
#         date var1 var2 Q_var1.Q25 Q_var1.Q75 Q_var2.Q25 Q_var2.Q75
#1: 2017-02-23    1    1       3.50       6.50          8       16.5
#2: 2017-02-22    3    3       3.00       3.00          3        3.0
#3: 2017-02-23    6   18       3.50       6.50          8       16.5
#4: 2017-02-23    7   15       3.50       6.50          8       16.5
#5: 2018-02-22    8   25       5.75       7.25         10       20.0
#6: 2018-02-22    5    5       5.75       7.25         10       20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base solution in case that's your jam. First, I define the data frame.

```r
# Original data frame
d <- data.frame(date = c("2017-02-23", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-23","2018-02-22", "2018-02-22"), 
                var1 = c(1,3,6,7,8,5), 
                var2 = c(1,3,18,15,25,5))
```

Next, I define a function that calculates the quantiles and binds them to the original data.

```r
# Function to calculate quantiles
foo <- function(x){
  q <- quantile(x, prob = c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = TRUE)
  data.frame(x, q25 = q[1], q75 = q[2], row.names = NULL)
}
```

I apply the function to each variable for each date, then `rbind` the results into a single data frame.

```r
# The horror...
d2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(levels(d$date), 
                            function(x) data.frame(date = x, lapply(d[d$date == x, names(d) != "date"], foo))))
```

This gives the following.

```r
# print results
d2
#>         date var1.x var1.q25 var1.q75 var2.x var2.q25 var2.q75
#> 1 2017-02-22      3     3.00     3.00      3        3      3.0
#> 2 2017-02-23      1     3.50     6.50      1        8     16.5
#> 3 2017-02-23      6     3.50     6.50     18        8     16.5
#> 4 2017-02-23      7     3.50     6.50     15        8     16.5
#> 5 2018-02-22      8     5.75     7.25     25       10     20.0
#> 6 2018-02-22      5     5.75     7.25      5       10     20.0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

An issue with this approach, unlike @akrun's (better) solutions, is that it reorders your data frame.